# How to compare two dates in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, momentjs

I am using moment.js in my application, I pass my date in a particular format to moment.js and it compares it with the system time and give me the pretty time format, like this:

```
moment(time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").fromNow();
```

Here the time is given by me as a timestamp in the specified format.

My problem is that fromNow() function takes the system date and not the server date. So, if a user uses his phone with 5 min delay time in his system he will get 4 min ago as the latest updated cards.

I want to compare "time" that I pass with the server time, that also will be passed by me.

Comment: While I agree the question in the title is a duplicate, the body is actually asking something different. Maybe the title could just be improved to match the question asked (e.g. "How to format durations between 2 dates in moment.js")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in 2 dates from your server: the existing timestamp, and the server's "now" timestamp.

Then (assuming your server passes in its timestamp in the same format) you can use [`.from()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) instead of `.fromNow()` do:

```
moment(time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").from(serverTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

If this is the only thing you're using the timestamp for, you could just have the server calculate & return the delta directly (let's call it `serverDeltaMs`) & format that using [`moment.duration(serverDeltaMs).humanize()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/).